# Angular two way binding in ngFor

Tags: angular

In Anguar 6, I have an ngFor which includes a select field. The selected-value of this field should be bound to the Category Property of SeatBookingModel that i use in ngFor. As this is of type CategoryModel i could be able to display the .Price Property of the CategoryModel.

What am I doing wrong here? The value for Category is not beeing set.
Template:

```
 <form>
  <table class="table">
    <tbody *ngFor="let bk of seatsReserved; let in=index">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span>{{ bk.SeatNumber }} </span>
        </td>
        <td>
           <select class="form-control" name="ddlCategory_{{in}}">
            <option *ngFor="let cat of getCategories(bk.SeatNumber)" [(ngValue)]="bk.Category" >{{cat.Name}}</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
         <span>{{ bk.Category.Price }}</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Parts of Controller:

```
export class SeatPlanComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private dataService: DataService) { 
  }

  seatsAlreadyTaken: Array<String>;

  seatsReserved: Array<SeatBookingModel>;

getCategories(seatNr: String) {
    let mock1 = new CategoryModel();
    mock1.Id = 1;
    mock1.Name = "Erwachsen";
    mock1.Price = 27.00;

    let mock2 = new CategoryModel();
    mock2.Id = 2;
    mock2.Name = "Student";
    mock2.Price = 22.00;
    return [mock1, mock2];
  }
```

SeatBookingModel:

```
export class SeatBookingModel {
    SeatNumber : String;
    Category: CategoryModel;
}
```

CategoryModel:

```
export class CategoryModel {
    Id : Number;
    Name: String;
    Price: Number;
}
```

Comment: can you post your data that you are binding

Comment: ngValue isn't known property of option, you should use  ```[value]="bk.Category.Name"```

Comment: @Sajeetharan I've added the getCategories(..) Method above.

Comment: i think you want something like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-example-dtpq8w), check it please.

Comment: @fatemefazli Thanks for the stackblitz, but this only works without the ngFor. I need this to work with multiple rows. I've  forked your stackblitz and updated it to mutiple rows: https://angular-select-example-fyt8mq.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 3):

`ngValue` directive directive should be used as `attribute binding`, its not two way bind able directive.

```
[(ngValue)]="bk.Category"
```

should be

```
[ngValue]="bk.Category"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
      <option *ngFor="let bk of selectOptions" [ngValue]="bk.Category.Name">
        {{bk.Category.Name}}
      </option>
</select>
{{ "selectedOption: " + selectedOption }}
```

ts code:

```
// the option you selected; this is the model you bind to the select element.
// this also will hold the selected option/value when you change the select


public selectOptions:SeatBookingModel[] = [
   { SeatNumber : 'test1' , Category:{
     Id : 44,
     Name: 'test',
     Price: 4,
   }
  }
]; 

public selectedOption = "test";
```

Answer (score 0):

Ngvalue doesn't support two way binding , you can use (onChange)=yourChangeFunction() to get/update your value.

Answer (score 0):

We can't bind `ngValue` directive as two way.

Here, you are making it 2-way like `[()]`(Banana in the box), this syntax binds the value two-way.
For directives you should do one-way `[]`(Only Box).

So your statement `[(ngValue)]="bk.Category"` should be `[ngValue]="bk.Category"`